# Validate JSON object using a Schema Definition

Tags: json

Just we can validate an incoming XML file based on the pre-defined schema, i.e. XSD or DTD, can we performation a validtaion on an incoming JSON object. Is there any JSON Schema Definition available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a working draft of a [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/). You could also take a look at [Cerny](http://www.cerny-online.com/cerny.js/).

Answer (score 1):

There are few libraries, which validate data against JSON Schema....

- [Amanda](https://github.com/Baggz/Amanda)
- [Revalidator](https://github.com/flatiron/revalidator)
- [JSV](https://github.com/garycourt/JSV)
- [Schema.js](https://github.com/akidee/schema.js)

Answer (score 1):

There's a new library, [json-gate](https://github.com/oferei/json-gate), that does the trick. (Full disclosure: I am the author.)

It is similar to JSV and others, but it has several advantages:

- It is fast*.
- It produces human-friendly, detailed error messages - for both you and your customers.
- Friendly, extensive [documentation](https://github.com/oferei/json-gate#readme). Not only of the library but of JSON schema as well!
- The schema is pre-validated. This allows you, the developer, to know right away if your schema definition is malformed. And it makes things run a little faster.

* It is not fast so much as JSV is *incredibly* slow. My test shows JSV to be 30 (!) times slower than *json-gate*. This result is consistent with [Robert Schultz's tests](http://cosmicrealms.com/blog/2012/01/13/benchmark-of-node-dot-js-json-validation-modules/), which compare JSV against other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

http://json-schema.org/implementations.html gives a list of validators.

There are 32 validators listed as of November 2015. One of them is available as an interactive online tool: http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

The others are grouped by implementation language.

In many cases, an indication of whether the validator supports the current version of JSON Schema is also given.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAPI is probably the best answer to this now.  It's supported in .Net 5.0.  This seems to be the industry direction.