# I always get undefined with a simple function and I don't know why in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I have to check data and log errors in an array. I have to write a function that does this. I have done that, but I always get an undefined. How is that? Where is my error?

```
'use strict';

// data to check
const receivedData = {
  age: 'twenty', //only numbers
  fruits: [
    {
      type: 'banana',
      amount: 5,
    },
    {
      type: 'apple',
      amount: 1.5,
    }, //only whole fruits .5 is not allowed
    {
      type: 'banana',
      amount: 2,
    },
    {
      type: 'banana',
      amount: 1.5,
    },
    {
      type: 'apple',
      amount: 2,
    },
  ],
};

const log = [];
const validateLog = (receivedData) => {
  //check age
  const age = 'age';
  const ageData = receivedData[age];
  console.log(ageData);
  const validateAge = Math.sign(ageData);
  const validateDataAge =
    validateAge !== 1 ? log.push(`${ageData} is not a age`) : ''; 
};
console.log(validateLog(receivedData));
console.log(log);
```

Comment: The `validateLog` function doesn't return anything.  What are you expecting to be logged to the console on that second-to-last line of code?

Comment: @David Oh man, thank you, I'm going crazy. I can't get my head around this. I'm so focused on the fact that it has to be a function that I'm missing the important things. Like just now. Thanks, I'll keep trying.Of course, I also get a good minus for the stupid question, lol.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905981/validate-json-object-using-a-schema-definition

Answer (score 1):

You should do a loop through each fruit to validate amount.

`Number.isInteger(x)` could help you checking if a value is and integer (or not), as it return true if x is an integer

`isNaN(x)` could help you checking if your age is a number or a string, as this return false if x is a number

And your function doesn't return anything, so you get undefined when trying to put that on `console.log()`

This looks like homework, so i won't give you the code for this, but i hope this will put you in the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting un defined since the validateLog arrow function doesn't return anything, hence undefined is returned since it's the default return value for functions and a function without a return statement will return a default value.